# Can't drag-drop a class between 2 packages in Android Studio

Tags: macos, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio on my MAC. I can't drag-drop a class between 2 packages (for example from package `service` to package `ui`). When I do, the Android Studio become unresponsive and I can't do anymore. I have to Force Close it and run again.

My Android Studio: version 2.1 preview 1. My Java SDK: 8

Please see the picture: Any help will appreciate.

[image]